# Preventing LocatorPane Locator from moving when PlotRange changes

Tags: manipulate, locator

I have a `LocatorPane` within a `Manipulate` such that the range of the plot behind the `Locator` can vary. When it does, this naturally causes the `Locator` to move on-screen to remain at a constant position with respect to the plot data. However, for my purposes, I need to prevent it from doing that. Ideally, it should stay at the same spot on-screen when the plot range is changed.

Here's a minimal example of the situation. Dragging the slider causes the `Locator` to move on-screen. Calculating the approximate position of the `Locator` as a fraction of the total plot size is easy, and a `Dynamic` displaying that is included. As mentioned in the `Manipulate` code, that value will ideally not change when the plot range is modified.

```
(* I need "point" (the locator's position) to always remain at the
   same position on-screen when end is changed. *)
Manipulate[
    Row[{
        LocatorPane[
            Dynamic[point],
            Plot[x, {x, 0, end}, ImageSize -> 400]
        ],
        "This value should change ONLY when the Locator is dragged: ",
        Dynamic[point / end]
    }],
    {end, 1, 2}
]
```

Notes:

- Using a `Locator` directly or via a `Manipulate` control is not allowed -- the locator *must* come from a `LocatorPane`. (Reason: I also need to be able to restrict the `Locator` to a certain rectangular region, and doing that with a raw `Locator` is possible but relatively slow.)
- Preventing the range of the plot within the `LocatorPane` from changing is also impossible (although wrapping it in another plot somehow is fine, if that is possible and helps).
- Using intermediate variables is fine: my attempts to solve the problem thus far have mainly involved separate `abspt` and `relpt` (absolute/relative point position) variables.

I have a feeling that there's some clever way to accomplish this with `Dynamic`, but I'm not familiar enough with `Dynamic` to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same logic as [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund) in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115964/18476).

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[point],
    Plot[x, {x, 0, end}, ImageSize -> 400]],
   "This value should change ONLY when the Locator is dragged: ", 
   Dynamic[point/end]}], 
  {{point, {0.5, 0.5}}, None}, {{scaledPoint, {0.5, 0.5}}, None}, 
  {end, 1, 2, 
   TrackingFunction :> {(scaledPoint = point/end; &), 
    (end = #; point = end*scaledPoint; &), None}}]
```

[image: outGIF]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the function evaluation syntax of `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[point], 
    Plot[x, {x, 0, end}, ImageSize -> 400]], 
   "This value should change ONLY when the Locator is dragged: ", 
   Dynamic[point/end]}],
 Row[{Slider[Dynamic[end, {(ss = point/end;) &, (end = #; point = end ss) &}], {1, 2}]}],
 Initialization :> {point = {1, 1};}
]
```

From the documentation for `LocatorPane`:

> For a Graphics object g, LocatorPane[pt,g] by default takes the range of coordinates for pt to be the range of graphics coordinates corresponding to PlotRange in g.

We can get around this.  The `Dynamic` for `end` in `Slider` captures the scaled position of the `Locator` at the start of moving the slider. Then, as it is moved it updates `point` to the new scaled position.  In the case were the x- and y-axis plot range changes non-linearly and/or at different rates you will need to account for this in your rescaling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, this causes recursion errors on a fresh kernel session until the locator is first dragged: [image 1](http://i.imgur.com/bopXfQb.png) , [image 2](http://i.imgur.com/QMRmmaW.png) . Also, the `Slider` no longer seems to slide smoothly, even with `ContinuousAction -> True` explicitly set. Can these issues be worked around? (I'm writing a Wolfram Demonstration submission, so I need everything to work as smoothly as possible.)

Comment: @KevinS Initialize `point` to stop recursion error in fresh kernel. See update.